# Where is the NodeJS file located containing 'require' function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I am trying to run a code that has `require()` function in it. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I have search online and I realized this is a NodeJS function. How can I find the file in NodeJS and can I solve the problem by simply putting the NodeJS file in my project folder?

Comment: Can you provide snippet ?

Comment: Are you trying to `require` in a web browser?

Comment: You run your script via NodeJS and get `require is not defined`? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: did you run npm install on your project root?

Comment: Where did you run this code?

Comment: "*Can I solve the problem by simply putting the file in my project folder?*" -  no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)